# Sublime 3 key binding for "Views -> Groups -> Max Columns: 2"

Tags: editor, sublimetext3

In Sublime text editor, there no key binding for group by columns.
What will be the key binding JSON for "Views -> Groups -> Max Columns: 2"?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to determine the command and arguments needed to bind a key to a menu item is to open the console with `View > Show Console`, then enter the command `sublime.log_commands(True)` and pick the menu item that you want to bind to and see what the console says.

In this case, the result is the following:

```
>>> sublime.log_commands(True)
command: set_max_columns {"columns": 2}
```

With that information, you can create a binding something like this (replace the key as appropriate):

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"],
    "command": "set_max_columns",
    "args": {"columns": 2}
},
```

Once you make the change, you'll see the menu item showing you the keyboard shortcut that you selected as a reminder.

The command logging will remain in effect until you run the same command again with `False` as a parameter or restart Sublime.